# How can i have third condition in my sorting?

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

I have the following array

```
let arr = [
    {
        auctionProductName: "m",
        pricePerUnitPerHour: 1,
        quanitity:20
    },
    {
        auctionProductName: "m",
        pricePerUnitPerHour: 22,
        quanitity:20
    },
    {
        auctionProductName: "a",
        pricePerUnitPerHour: 5555,
        quanitity:20
    },
    {
        auctionProductName: "a",
        pricePerUnitPerHour: 22,
        quanitity:20
    },
    {
        id:1,
        auctionProductName: "a",
        pricePerUnitPerHour: 22,
        quanitity:20
    },
   
    {
        auctionProductName: "m",
        pricePerUnitPerHour: 2222,
        quanitity:20
    },

    {
        id:2,
        auctionProductName: "a",
        pricePerUnitPerHour: 22,
        quanitity:2
    },
]
```

so this array need to be sorted firstly ASCENDING on auctionProductName, if there are same objects after this sorting by auctionProductName then they need to be sorted by pricePerUnitPerHour.

For that i have the following code which works as expected

```
function defaultTableSort() {
    arr = arr.sort(
        function (a, b) {
          if (a.auctionProductName === b.auctionProductName) {
            return a.pricePerUnitPerHour - b.pricePerUnitPerHour;
          }
          return a.auctionProductName > b.auctionProductName ? 1 : -1;
    });
}
```

after the sorting i get

```
[
    {
        "auctionProductName": "a",
        "pricePerUnitPerHour": 22,
        "quanitity": 20
    },
    {
        "id": 1,
        "auctionProductName": "a",
        "pricePerUnitPerHour": 22,
        "quanitity": 20
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "auctionProductName": "a",
        "pricePerUnitPerHour": 22,
        "quanitity": 2
    },
    {
        "auctionProductName": "a",
        "pricePerUnitPerHour": 5555,
        "quanitity": 20
    },
    {
        "auctionProductName": "m",
        "pricePerUnitPerHour": 1,
        "quanitity": 20
    },
    {
        "auctionProductName": "m",
        "pricePerUnitPerHour": 22,
        "quanitity": 20
    },
    {
        "auctionProductName": "m",
        "pricePerUnitPerHour": 2222,
        "quanitity": 20
    }
]
```

i can't find a way to modify my `defaultTableSort` function - so the third condition will be by quantity -

if the auctionProductName and pricePerUnitPerHour are same, than we should sort by quantity.

That means that the third object ( AFTER THE SORTING ) with id of 2 needs to be before the second object with id of 1.

Answer (score 2):

You could chain the wanted sorting.

For getting a descending sorting, you could exchange `a` and `b`.

```js
const
    array = [{ auctionProductName: "m", pricePerUnitPerHour: 1, quanitity: 20 }, { auctionProductName: "m", pricePerUnitPerHour: 22, quanitity: 20 }, { auctionProductName: "a", pricePerUnitPerHour: 5555, quanitity: 20 }, { auctionProductName: "a", pricePerUnitPerHour: 22, quanitity: 20 }, { id: 1, auctionProductName: "a", pricePerUnitPerHour: 22, quanitity: 20 }, { auctionProductName: "m", pricePerUnitPerHour: 2222, quanitity: 20 }, { id: 2, auctionProductName: "a", pricePerUnitPerHour: 22, quanitity: 2 }];

array.sort((a, b) =>
    a.auctionProductName.localeCompare(b.auctionProductName) ||
    a.pricePerUnitPerHour - b.pricePerUnitPerHour ||
    a.quanitity - b.quanitity
);

console.log(array);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add another if clause

```
function (a, b) {
      if (a.auctionProductName === b.auctionProductName) {
        if(a.pricePerUnitPerHour === a.pricePerUnitPerHour)
             return a.quantity - b.quantity;
        return a.pricePerUnitPerHour - b.pricePerUnitPerHour;
      }
      return a.auctionProductName > b.auctionProductName ? 1 : -1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can other conditional structure for verify if:

`a.pricePerUnitPerHour === b.pricePerUnitPerHour`

with a final code:

```js
function defaultTableSort() {
    arr = arr.sort(
        function (a, b) {
            
          if (a.auctionProductName === b.auctionProductName) {
            // auctionProductName is equal between a and b
            
            if (a.pricePerUnitPerHour === b.pricePerUnitPerHour) {
                // pricePerUnitPerHour is equal between a and b
                
                // sort based on: quantity
                return a.quantity - b.quantity
            }
            
            // sort based on: pricePerUnitPerHour
            return a.pricePerUnitPerHour - b.pricePerUnitPerHour;
          }
          
          // sort based on: auctionProductName
          return a.auctionProductName > b.auctionProductName ? 1 : -1;
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Rather than nesting if statements you could

```
function defaultTableSort() {
    return arr = arr.sort(
        function (a, b) {
          if (a.auctionProductName === b.auctionProductName && a.pricePerUnitPerHour === b.pricePerUnitPerHour) {
            return a.quanitity - b.quanitity;
          }
          if (a.auctionProductName === b.auctionProductName) {
            return a.pricePerUnitPerHour - b.pricePerUnitPerHour;
          }
          return a.auctionProductName > b.auctionProductName ? 1 : -1;
    });
}
```

And that has the output

```
[{
  "id": 2,
  "auctionProductName": "a",
  "pricePerUnitPerHour": 22,
  "quanitity": 2
}, {
  "auctionProductName": "a",
  "pricePerUnitPerHour": 22,
  "quanitity": 20
}, {
  "id": 1,
  "auctionProductName": "a",
  "pricePerUnitPerHour": 22,
  "quanitity": 20
}, {
  "auctionProductName": "a",
  "pricePerUnitPerHour": 5555,
  "quanitity": 20
}, {
  "auctionProductName": "m",
  "pricePerUnitPerHour": 1,
  "quanitity": 20
}, {
  "auctionProductName": "m",
  "pricePerUnitPerHour": 22,
  "quanitity": 20
}, {
  "auctionProductName": "m",
  "pricePerUnitPerHour": 2222,
  "quanitity": 20
}]
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
const arr = [
  {
    auctionProductName: 'm',
    pricePerUnitPerHour: 1,
    quanitity: 20,
  },
  {
    auctionProductName: 'm',
    pricePerUnitPerHour: 22,
    quanitity: 20,
  },
  {
    auctionProductName: 'a',
    pricePerUnitPerHour: 5555,
    quanitity: 20,
  },
  {
    auctionProductName: 'a',
    pricePerUnitPerHour: 22,
    quanitity: 20,
  },
  {
    id: 1,
    auctionProductName: 'a',
    pricePerUnitPerHour: 22,
    quanitity: 20,
  },

  {
    auctionProductName: 'm',
    pricePerUnitPerHour: 2222,
    quanitity: 20,
  },

  {
    id: 2,
    auctionProductName: 'a',
    pricePerUnitPerHour: 22,
    quanitity: 2,
  },
];
const orderBy = (arr, props, orders) =>
  [...arr].sort((a, b) =>
    props.reduce((acc, prop, i) => {
      if (acc === 0) {
        const [p1, p2] = orders && orders[i] === 'desc' ? [b[prop], a[prop]] : [a[prop], b[prop]];
        acc = p1 > p2 ? 1 : p1 < p2 ? -1 : 0;
      }
      return acc;
    }, 0)
  );
console.log(
  JSON.stringify(
    orderBy(arr, ['auctionProductName', 'pricePerUnitPerHour', 'quanitity'] /*, ['desc', 'desc', 'desc']*/),
    null,
    2
  )
);
```